# MapReduce programming to filter a large input file

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a very large input text file with the following format:

```
ID \t time \t product \t Description \t Status
```

The Status column is limited to contain either lower case a,s,i or upper case A,S,I or a mixed of the two (sample element in status col: a,si, I, asi, ASI, aSI, Asi...)

What I want to achieve is to filter out this output file based on Status using MapReduce. I want to discard all rows in the original file that has at least 1 upper case letter in the status. In other words, I only care about the rows that have all lower case letters in the status.

I'm new to MapReduce programming and needs some help. Below is what I have come up with so far

My mapper.py is:

```
import sys
import re

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    portions = re.split(r'\t+', line)
    status = portions[-1] #pop out last item (status info) from portions list
    #Now I want to emit key as status and value as the portions list
    print '%s\t%s' % (status, portions) #obviously, I don't think it's correct, I got stuck at this part
```

my reducer.py is:

```
import sys

#I'm assuming that I have read in status and portions.
#In my understanding, the number of output files depend on the number of reducers. But what I want is to discard all rows that has at least 1 upper case letter in status bar.
#The file output should be a single file with rows that have all lower case letters in status bar.
```

I think checking if status has at least 1 upper case is not hard, but I got stuck at how to discard rows that are not my interest and combine all output files into one file with the same format as in the original text file.

Any help to direct me to the right path is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this without the reducer at all,

Something like this in your mapper:

```
import sys
import re

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    portions = re.split(r'\t+', line)
    status = portions[-1]
    if status.islower():
        whatever_you_want_to_write = status + ',' + portions #whatever
        sys.stdout.write(whatever_you_want_to_write)
```

See the documentation of [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/streaming.html) for details on reading/writing to HDFS.

Something like this, for example:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -output myOutputDir \
    -mapper myPythonScript.py \
    -jobconf mapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
    -file myPythonScript.py
```

Notice how you can specify `-jobconf mapred.reduce.tasks=0` to tell Hadoop that you won't be needing a reduce step.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ComputerFellow. I think that I over-thought about this problem. I guess when you say "sys.stdout.write" to write to stdout, I could replace it with writing to a file instead, right? If I'm not wrong, I will need to append new text to the file since every mapper will write to the same file.

Comment: @LKT but if you want to write to a file - it would probably not be on HDFS, the best way is to write to stdout and let HDFS streaming do the job when you specify `-output`. Do not get your hands dirty with writing to a file when on Hadoop - it defeats the purpose...

Comment: I see. Thanks again, I'm still so new to the Hadoop and not used to utilize it yet. So if I specify the output, Hadoop will write whatever I have in stdout from each mapper into a single file?

Comment: @LKT probably not always a single file, but under a single directory, which you can always `cat *` if you'd like - but beware if your output filesize is huge - there's not point in storing all of the output in a single file...